# What is the path of a member belonging to multiple hierarchies?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a dimension (`d_orga`) with the following structure : http://dongorath.free.fr/d_orga.png.

As you can see, there is a hierarchy for each parallel branch.

My problem is determining the key path of a member at the `l_site` level, knowing that each member has a parent in every branch. An exemple member is : `[d_orga].[l_site].&[grp]&[p3]&[e3]&[c3]&[eu]&[DE]&[ber]`. This tells me it wants all levels in the order `l_grp - l_pol - l_ent - l_com - l_reg - l_cou - l_site` for my specific case, but those specific hierarchies can be different depending on the client (this example is our "demo" environment whereas a client could have different levels, or only 2 hierarchies, etc.). How can I determine the order of the wanted levels without having to hardcode it each time ? Does it depends on the creation order of the hierarchies ? An alphabetical order I failed to see ? Another arcane inner working of SSAS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has, in fact, nothing to do with the structure of the dimension. The key path of a member is "simply" the key columns (property `KeyColumns`) defined on the attribute. They are ordered when defined and this is the order that must be used.

In the example of the question, I defined the key columns of the `l_site` attribute to be, in order, `grp_code - pol_code - ent_code - com_code - reg_code - cou_code - site_code`, thus, it is the order to be used.

Concerning the problem of specific hierarchies in client applications, the definition of the key columns being computed by the application, it can be safely re-computed by this very application.